# How to fit JS into if statement

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I want to put a bit of JavaScript into a PHP if. like below. However I can not get it to work properly, advice?

```
    if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Condition') {
            '<script language="javascript">
function displayCondition() {
condition = new Array("Please Select a Condition.","<b>Perfect:</b> Text to explain perfect condition!", "<b>Excellent:</b> Text to explain excellent condition!", "<b>Good:</b> Text to explain good condition!", "<b>Poor:</b> Text to explain poor condition!", "<b>Broken:</b> Text to explain broken condition!");
var getsel = document.getElementById(\'select_'.$_option->getId().'\').value;
document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
}
</script>';
            $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();"';
        } else if 
            ($_option->getTitle() == 'Original Packaging') {
            $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();Select(select_'.$_option->getId().',\'divShow\',2);"';
        } else {
            $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();"';
        }
```

Comment: What does that mean, "can't get it to work properly"? What does it do and what do you expect it to?

Comment: The javascript portion doesn't work. It is not printing it in the code when the condition is met.

Comment: Maybe because you're just creating a string, but are not *outputting* it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mix PHP and HTML (including JavaScript), you have to pay attention to PHP opening tags :

```
if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Condition') {
    // go out of PHP
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
       function displayCondition() {
         condition = new Array("Please Select a Condition.","<b>Perfect:</b> Text to explain perfect condition!", "<b>Excellent:</b> Text to explain excellent condition!", "<b>Good:</b> Text to explain good condition!", "<b>Poor:</b> Text to explain poor condition!", "<b>Broken:</b> Text to explain broken condition!");
         var getsel = document.getElementById('select_<?php echo $_option->getId(); ?>').value;
         document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
       }
    </script>
    <?php
    // back to php
    $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();"';
```

You could also have tried to make a big `echo`, but that involves to handle quote escapement and is generally heavier.

Comment: there is a php part in that js which you missed

Comment: @MarkoD Yes. It's hard to edit those long lines...

Comment: Thank you works perfect. Now I have a different issue. I will make a new question. Your great.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you echo out the `<script>`.

```
<?php if (condition) {
  echo '<script> //do stuff </script>';
?>
```

or alternatively use the [alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) to include the `<script>` into the page

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
  <script> //do stuff </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write this way

```
 $extraParams = "";
if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Condition') {
$extraParams .= '<script>...you script </script>';

$extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();displayCondition();"';
    } else if 
        ($_option->getTitle() == 'Original Packaging') {
        $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();Select(select_'.$_option->getId().',\'divShow\',2);"';
    } else {
        $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice();"';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [PHP's HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) when dealing with large markups in PHP.

```
$script_tage = <<<HEREDOC
<script language="javascript">
    function displayCondition() {
    condition = ["Please Select a Condition.","<b>Perfect:</b> Text to explain perfect condition!", "<b>Excellent:</b> Text to explain excellent condition!", "<b>Good:</b> Text to explain good condition!", "<b>Poor:</b> Text to explain poor condition!", "<b>Broken:</b> Text to explain broken condition!"];
    var getsel = document.getElementById('select_'.{$_option->getId()}).value;
    document.getElementById("divId").innerHTML = condition[getsel];
</script>
HEREDOC;


if ($_option->getTitle() == 'Condition') {
    echo $script_tag;
}
```

**Note**- there is no need to escape anything in HEREDOC. To enter variables in the HEREDOC string, just put them in a pair of braces like `{$foo}`.